# remove the need of Authentication to access files in ubuntu

Tags: 19.10, authentication

I tried steps mentioned below, but I cannot found the `PasswordAuthentication`

1. Log into Ubuntu and click "Applications," "Accessories," then "Terminal."
2. Type `sudo nano /etc/sshd_config`. Enter your administrative login password when prompted.
3. Press "Ctrl+W" on the keyboard to open a "Search" window. Type `PasswordAuthentication and press "Enter."
4. Remove the "#" sign at the start of the `PasswordAuthentication` label, then replace "Yes" with "No" so that the line reads: `PasswordAuthentication no`

How can I remove this?

Comment: That should be `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Did you mistype?

Comment: @StephenBoston  I want to remove the always asking about the authentication when I log in to any file they ask my password i want to disable it. How can I do this ?

Comment: @StephenBoston  no ,i cant find the PasswordAuthentication

Comment: `sudo nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config` and reverse your edits.

Comment: @StephenBoston that would be `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. Please explain more. Why did you edit ssh_config?

Comment: When I open any file  ubuntu 19.10 asked password always  to use my internal hard(there are two hards in my machine ssd  and normal one, SSD with windos and other one with ubuntu 19.10 and linux mint  ).When I want to access other partition  they asked password always. not only once when  open any file  they asked again and again. thats the matter